# Why is the new Facebook "is using [app name]" showing "http://localhost:3000" for my app name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, localhost

Facebook apps now show a right column with friends using apps and icons for the apps.  For one of the apps I developed, it's saying "[name] is using http://localhost:3000", even though the app is not hosted at localhost:3000.  When I was developing it, I used localhost:3000, so I'm thinking it's some sort of caching issue with Facebook.  Is there somewhere I can change this in developers.facebook.com?  Do I need to use OG tags to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Change your site URL in https://developers.facebook.com/apps to your live domain.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Facebook Linter to refresh the cache on your application and see if it helps.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug